# How can I split list items across columns and rows?

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a responsive layout with Bootstrap. I have a list need to split the items across 2 columns and 2 rows.

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</>
<li>item 2</>
<li>item 3</>
<li>item 4</>
</ul>
```

so my ul css - flex-direction: row;
which lists the items in a row side each other

then at a media query - css flex-direction: column;
so they stack on top of each other

I would like the 3rd and 4th item to be like this so bascialy 2 columns
Is this possible?

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</>   <li>item 3</>
<li>item 2</>   <li>item 4</>
</ul>
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <ul>
    <li>item 1</>
    <li>item 2</>
    <li>item 3</>
    <li>item 4</>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please look more closely at the editor toolbar so you learn how to format code. Also, your question seems to ask how to format the code itself rather than the rendered output. Is that right?

Comment: Please revise the demo I added above to show your attempt. Note that every closing list item tag up there is malformed. They should be like `</li>`.

Answer (score 0):

We can't split list items into a grid since that would require invalid HTML. However, we can extend Bootstrap's [sizing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent) for our purposes. We'll align them with Bootstrap's [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints).

There may be a simpler way to employ [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/) here to wrap appropriately, but I haven't come up with it.

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .w-100.w-sm-50 {
    width: 50% !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .w-100.w-md-25 {
    width: 25% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <li class="w-100 w-sm-50 w-md-25">item</li>
  <li class="w-100 w-sm-50 w-md-25">item</li>
  <li class="w-100 w-sm-50 w-md-25">item</li>
  <li class="w-100 w-sm-50 w-md-25">item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.